# Create a "products you may be interested in" algorithm in SQL?

Tags: sql, algorithm, search, product, similarity

i have a problem which im not sure how to approach.

I have a simple database where i store products , users , and purchases of products by users. 
Each product has a name , a category and a price.

My goal is the following :
I want to display a list of 5 items that are suggested as "You might be interested in" to the user.The main problem is that i don't just want to search LIKE %..% for the name , but i also want to take into account the types of products the user usually buys , the price range he usually buys at , and giving priority to products being bought more often.

Is such an algorithm realistic? I can think of some metrics , like grouping all categories into semantically "similar" buckets and calculating distance from that , but im not sure how i should rank them when there is multiple criteria.

Maybe i should give each criteria an importance factor and have the result be a multiplication of the distance * the factor?

Comment: Are you working on a specific DBMS ?

Comment: It's actually for a Spring data + JPA project but that is a mess so let's assume it's MySql / MariaDB

Comment: This is a classic data science type problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create 2 additional fields for each product in your database. In the first field called Type for example you could say "RC" and in the second field called similar you could say, "RC, Radio, Electronics, Remote, Model" Then in your query in SQL later on you can tell it to select products that match up between type and similar. This provides a system that doesn't just rely on the product name, as these can be deceiving. It would be still using the LIKE command, but it would be far more accurate as it's pre-defined by you as to what other products are similar to this one.

Depending on the size of your database already, I believe this to be the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

I was using this on MySql for some weighted search :

```
SELECT *,
    IF(
        `libelle` LIKE :startSearch,  30,
        IF(`libelle` LIKE :fullSearch, 20, 0)
    )
    + IF(
        `description` LIKE :startSearch, 10,
        IF(`description` LIKE :fullSearch, 5, 0)
    )
    + IF(
        `keyword` LIKE :fullSearch, 1, 0
    )
    AS `weight`
FROM `t`
WHERE (
    -- at least 1 match
    `libelle` LIKE :fullSearch
    OR `description` LIKE :fullSearch
    OR `keyword` LIKE :fullSearch
)
ORDER BY
        `weight` DESC

/*
'fullSearch'=>'%'.str_replace(' ', '_', trim($search)).'%',
'startSearch'=>str_replace(' ', '_', trim($search)).'%',
*/
```